# How to set document's title per page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am actually using the `pages/_document.js` hook to add `Bootstrap` and `jQuery` to my pages, by the way I set the `<Head>`

```
export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <Head>
          <title>Default title</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/lib/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        </Head>

        <body>
          <Main/>
          <NextScript/>
          <script src="/static/lib/jquery3/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" />
          <script src="/static/lib/bootstrap3/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}
```

Now I would like to set a different Title,for my pages. Is it possible to used `<Head>` outside of `Document` ? I mean in `<div>` like this:

```
const ContactPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>You better contact us!</title>
      </Head>

      <div className="page-body">...</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And if possible, will it overwrite or merge what is already set in `pages/_document.js` ?

Comment: document.title = "insert title here"

Comment: OK, I thought there was a Next.js specific way.

Comment: There might be, but I'm sure Common JS would work just fine here.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You want to use the `next/head` component:

```
import Head from 'next/head'

export default () =>
  <div>
    <Head>
      <title>My page title</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    </Head>

    <p>Hello world!</p>
  </div>
```

See the docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head

Comment: OK. But as I test it, if you set a tag in Head, in one page, for example the title, you will have to set it for all the others pages, because it will just unset what you put for the title in _document.js.

Comment: Don't use `_document.js` for things that change on different pages. Create a layout component and pass the title in as a property. Then wrap your pages in that layout. The `next.js` repository on github has many examples. You should take a look at them. For the title stuff, look at this one in particular: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/layout-component

Comment: OK I got it, Thanks

Answer (score 15):

***In NextJs v13 | v14 using the app directory*** you don't have to use the `'next/head'` component anymore. What you need to do instead is just define an exported object whether in `layout.js` OR `page.js` holding the title ***statically*** like the example below:

```js
export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};
```

Or if you need a **dynamic** title, you can use the `generateMetadata` function to achieve what you need like the example below:

```js
//in this example I use the generateMetadata function to generate a multi languages title.

export async function generateMetadata({ params: { lng } }) {

  const myTitle = lng === "en" ? "Hi" : "مرحبا";

  return {
    title: myTitle,
  };
}
```

Reference [Config-based Metadata](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata)

Comment: This generateMetadata will work only in Server Pages. How to give title and description in a Client Component. If you use generateMetadata in layout.js, title and description will be same for every page. Please correct me where I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: @jagdish-padeliya I think you miss understand the new Next.js 13, in Next.js 13 you can define layout.js for each page. also, you can use the `generateMetadata()` in layout.js OR page.js as I mentioned in the answer. I think you should read Next.js 13 docs for more understanding and read more about "use client" if you would like to render the component on the client side

Comment: Can you please have a look to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76441912/15384724

Comment: This worked. thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

When you need something more power full than `generateMetadata()` or `export const metadata: Metadata`  to **optimize** the server page render you can use this simple, not too clean way...

```
export default async function Page({params}: Props) {
   const extractedData = await extractData()
   const title = getTitle(params,extractedData);
   ...
   return <>
      <title>{title}</title>
      ...
     </>
  }
```

*Use this... until a better underlying architecture emerge.*